# Не получается использовать throttle в Lodash

Tags: lodash

Изучаю lodash, функция throttle. Решил потренироваться на выводе в консоль координат мыши.

```
window.onmousemove = (e) => {
                console.log('Мышь X: ' + e.clientX + ' Мышь Y: ' + e.clientY);
        };
```

Теперь добавляю throttle, и консоль перестаёт реагировать совсем. Почему этот код не работает?

```
window.onmousemove = (e) => {
            _.throttle(() => {
                console.log('Мышь X: ' + e.clientX + ' Мышь Y: ' + e.clientY);
            }, 1000);
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так снаружи надо добавлять, а не внутри.

```
window.onmousemove = _.throttle(
```